# Creating a round bowl shape with wavy edge

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, bezier-curves

I want to create a mesh like below.
[image]

I thought there are some ways to create this, but I don't think there is perfect way.

1. Make a curve part of the wave and apply array modifier.
   It is very direct way but hard to manipulate the wavy edge I think.
2. Make a wavy curve and roll it and extrude.
   It's easy to manipulate the wavy edge shape, but it will be a cylinderic shape, not a bowl.

Is there any better way for this? Or what's the better do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a perfect use case for geometry nodes (that's of course just my opinion), so with a node setup like this:

[image]

you can do these things here:

[image]

Comment: It is amazing but paradoxically decreasing productivity. You focused on the wavy edge, I mentioned though. As you can see, the example mesh has more details such like inner edge(sides are not perfectly sphere), sides angle(sides are not pointing perfect +Z) etc. I agree, it can be done by the code as well, however I don't think implementing is easier or faster than this one. But I will check as answer because showing about the geometry node system what I didn't consider.

Answer (score 4):

Start with a cube. Give it a Subdivision Surface Modifier (Level 2) and a Cast Modifier with the *Factor* set to 1. Apply them both in top to bottom order. This will give you a "round cube".

[image: RoundCube]

Select the top half of faces and delete them.

[image: FacesGone]

Select the top ring of vertices - select every other by using *Checker Deselect*

[image: Checker]

Move the selected vertices "down" on the Z-Axis, and then scale them in slightly to make them match the curvature of the rest of the "bowl"

[image: MoveVerts]

Add a Solidify Modifier and another Subdivision Surface modifier to make things rounded. Shade smooth to make it smoother:

[image: Smooth]

If you want more definition in the edges of the bowl, add a Bevel Modifier between the Solidify and Subdivision Surface Modifiers. You can play with some of these values to define slightly different "shapes"  to the edges. I recommend increasing the bevel angle to 31 so it doesn't bevel the edges running towards the bottom center of the bowl:

[image: BevelBowl]

Comment: Instead of moving the vertices down on the Z axis and scaling inwards eyeballing to keep the curvature I would rather double-tap G to edge slide the vertices down.